# Cordova file writing throws EACCES (Permission denied) error

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ngcordova

I was using `cordova-plugin-file` and `cordova-plugin-file-transfer` on Ionic mobile application to download some files to Android device which can open with native applications like pdf, word, excel..etc. This plugin was working perfectly before the Marshmallow os update.

It is now throwing `"exception":"/storage/emulated/0/logo_radni.png: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)"}`.

in config.xml file I have also added following permissions as well.

```
<platform name="android">
   <preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
   <preference name="AndroidExtraFilesystems" value="files,files-external,documents,sdcard,cache,cache-external,assets,root" />
</platform>
```

This is working on previous android os version. Here is my code sample

```
 angular.module('starter.controllers', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])
 .controller('DashCtrl', function ($scope, $ionicPlatform, $cordovaFileTransfer) {

    $scope.downloadFile = function () {
            $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {

              // File for download
                var url = "http://www.gajotres.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/logo_radni.png";

                // File name only
                var filename = url.split("/").pop();

                // Save location
                var targetPath = cordova.file.externalRootDirectory + filename;

                $cordovaFileTransfer.download(url, targetPath, {}, true).then(function (result) {
                    console.log('Success');
                }, function (error) {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
                }, function (progress) {
                    // PROGRESS HANDLING GOES HERE
                });
            });

        };
    })
```

Note:

I need to download files into `cordova.file.externalRootDirectory` to give access to other applications like pdf readers, word, excel..etc

Plugin References:

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer

http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/fileTransfer/

Any one have an idea to sort this out?

Comment: which version of cordova you using?

Comment: you can use `https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-android-permissions` this plugin for request permission

Comment: @DivyeshSavaliya I'm using version: 5.1.1, platformVersion: 5.1.1. The link that you provided is broken

Comment: On which android version are you deploying? And which plugin versions are you using?

Comment: @Beat, As i mentioned Android version is 6.0.1 (Marshmallow). Latest plugins from above reference

Comment: Ok I'm sorry, Can you please check plugin versions by `cordova plugins ls`

Comment: @Beat, sure.. it is name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" version="1.5.1" 
name="cordova-plugin-file" version="4.3.0"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After the investigation I was able to find the root cause of the issue. This permission issue error is throwing due to the OS Upgrade to Marshmallow. They have changed permission granting procedure. After the API level 23, applications won't get permission at the time of installation. Users have to grant permission at the time of using the Application. So I had to explicitly install a plugin to grant permissions at the time of using device resources.

I have written a quick blog post on this to share with the community. Also thanks @Beat as well :)

Anyone can refer the http://anishantha87.blogspot.com/2016/10/read-and-write-permission-for-storage.html for quick sample application.

You can find Android API Reference for OS Upgrade permissions [here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).

Hope this will be helpful for someone else.

Cheers!

Comment: Perfectly Working thank you so much... saved a lot of time

Answer (score 0):

I changed the android version in which the application is focused adding this tag in the config.xml:

```
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="28" />
```

And this change allows to save files into the device using mentioned cordova plugins on Android 8, Android 9, Android 10 and Android 11.

The Android documentation recommends to change the API Level version to avoid the scoped storage feature on Android 10.

You get more information about scoped storage feature here:
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/use-cases#opt-out-scoped-storage

Answer (score -2):

According to `cordova-plugin-file` docs, you have to set the permissions to write to external storage explicitly by adding this to your `config.xml`:

```
<platform name="android">
    <.../>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <.../>
</platform>
```

I think the documentation is a bit tricky to understand, but you can find already the required information in the [docs of cordova-plugin-file](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file#android):

> **sdcard**: The global external file storage directory (this is the root of the SD card, if one is installed). You must have the android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission to use this.

And for further reading I can recommend the official `android` [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal) in the related abstract:

> **Getting access to external storage**
>   In order to read or write files on the external storage, your app must acquire the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE or WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE system permissions...

Comment: I'm still trying to add permissions as you mentioned. Still couldn't get to it. ` <config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/manifest">
      <uses-permission name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
      <uses-permission name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    </config-file>`

Comment: Put it into your config.xml in your application root directory like mentionend in the [cordova docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/index.html#platform)